# Exercise 9 from Zed Shaw's Learn Python the hard way

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-2.x

Working on exercise 9 from Zed Shaw's Learn Python the hard way. I get the following error:

```
File "ex9.py", line 14
    """
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here's the complete code:

```
# Here's some strange new stuff, remember to type it exactly.

days = "Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun"
months = "Jan\nFeb\nMar\nApr\nMay\nJun\nJul\nAug\nSep\nOct\nNov\nDec"

print "Here are the days: ", days
print "Here are the months ", months

Print """ 
There's something going on here.
With the three double-quote.
We'll be able to type as much as we like.
Even 4 lines if we want, or 5, or 6. 
"""
```

Comment: Python is case-sensitive, the statement is `print` not `Print`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, the command is print, not Print. 
furthermore, try to type the """ directly yourself, and not copy-paste from somewhere (if that was the case)... some symbols can look very much alike, but still be different.